# What is going on with tensorflow dataset?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is the code that I wrote in google colab

These code is probably not the best, but it works and creates a tensorflow dataset with mnist digit dataset with tuples (image, label)

```
mnist_data = datasets.load_dataset("mnist")

class MnistGenerator():
    def __init__(self, train_data, test_data):
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.test_data = test_data

    def get_generator(self, train=True):
        data = self.train_data if train else self.test_data
        def generator():
            for row in data:
                image, label = row["image"], row["label"]
                numpy_image, numpy_label = tf.constant(np.asarray(image), dtype=tf.float64),
                                                          tf.constant(label, dtype=tf.float64)
                yield (numpy_image, numpy_label)
        return generator

Generator = MnistGenerator(mnist_data["train"], mnist_data["test"])
output_spec = (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(28, 28), dtype=tf.float64), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64))
tf_datasets = {
    "train": tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        Generator.get_generator(train=True),
        output_signature=output_spec
    ),
    "test": tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        Generator.get_generator(train=False),
        output_signature=output_spec
    )
}
```

Next, for my task, I decided to create for each digit a tensorflow dataset that contains images of this digit.

Also I created a dataset that `tf dataset process` that has normalized images in it

```
def normalize_image(X):
    X -= tf.math.reduce_mean(X)
    X /= tf.math.reduce_std(X)
    return X

tf_dataset_processed = tf_datasets["train"].map(lambda x, y: (normalize_image(x), y,))

class MnistGeneratorByLabel:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def get_generator(self, label):
        def generator():
            for x, y in self.data:
                if y == label:
                    yield x
        return generator

Generator = MnistGeneratorByLabel(tf_dataset_processed)
tf_label_datasets = {
    i : tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        Generator.get_generator(i),
        output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(28, 28), dtype=tf.float64)
    )
    for i in range(10)
}
```

For some reason even though I create `tf dataset label`  from `tf dataset process` when I look inside the former dataset its  images are not normalized. Help me please understand this problem

I looked up the tensorflow documentation, but I haven't managed to understand this issue

Comment: It seems like the normalization function normalize_image is being applied within the tf_dataset_processed dataset, but when you create the datasets for each label using MnistGeneratorByLabel, the normalization is not being preserved. This is because you are only extracting images from the dataset without applying the normalization function.

To fix this, you should ensure that the normalization function is applied to the images when creating datasets for each label. You can modify the MnistGeneratorByLabel class to include the normalization step.